# React Native IOS - Firebase authentification Network Request failed

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, networking, request

I've implemented a react native app with firebase integration.
Here signs the user in anonymously.

I upgraded react native to 0.60 and now the function signInAnonymously() returns an error "Network Request failed".
Description : "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."

- I already set the "Allow arbitrary Loads" to YES in Xcode
- I already set in iPhone Simulator Settings -> Developer -> Allow HTTP Services

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Here is my firebase.js file:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
const settings = {};

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyCg**********eRHumnb_iPpeB3yEA",
  authDomain: "**********.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://*********.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "*********",
  storageBucket: "**********.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "213******74",
  appId: "1:213******74:web:a******495f2"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
firebase.firestore().settings(settings);

export default firebase;
```

and my index.js file:

```
import firebase from "./src/service/Firebase"

firebase.auth().signInAnonymously().catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error.code);
    console.log(error.message);
});
```

And here is my package.json

```
"dependencies": {
    "@popmotion/popcorn": "^0.4.2",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/geolocation": "^2.0.2",
    "d3-shape": "^1.3.5",
    "firebase": "^6.5.0",
    "geofirestore": "^3.3.1",
    "native-base": "^2.13.5",
    "randomcolor": "^0.5.4",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.60.5",
    "react-native-card-stack-swiper": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-cardview": "^2.0.3",
    "react-native-easy-grid": "^0.2.2",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-firebase": "^5.5.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.4.1",
...
}
```

In my firebase console the user is signed in anonymously, but nevertheless the error occurs.

I've already read multiple threads about a similar problem but I did everything described above and nothing helped..

Can anybody help me?

Comment: did you ever solve this?  Have been unable to upgrade to 0.60 myself due to this issue.

Comment: I didn't find any solution but I recognized that the problem only appears when I debug the ios simulator remotely. If I do not debug, the network request fail does not appear

Comment: I have the same issue actually, but it's nearly impossible to develop if you can't use debug mode :(

Comment: That's correct and I don't know why this problem exists.. Unfortunately I am using lots of Alert.alert(xxx) in my coding to 'debug' since >0.6